# How to write prepared statement for a query containing multiple SELECT statements

Tags: php, mysql

I want to the following using prepared statements:

```
<?php 

$sql = "SELECT name FROM B WHERE profile_id IN (SELECT profile_id FROM A WHERE login_id='$email')
    UNION SELECT name FROM C WHERE profile_id IN (SELECT profile_id FROM A WHERE login_id='$email')";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

?>
```

Here, `A` is the main table, `B` and `C` are sub tables. In the main table, the primary key is `profile_id`. The tables `B` and `C` have a foreign key referencing `A`'s `profile_id`.

Comment: What does the documentation say and what problem are you having with it?

Comment: @Federico. I write normal select query in php mysql. We need to prepared select query for secure purpose.

Comment: that's not my question. I'm asking what problems you're having with the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), which explains in great detail what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT x.name 
  FROM A 
Join 
 ( Select Name,profile_id from b
   Union all
   Select name, profile_id from c
 ) x
 On 
  x. profile_id = a.profile_id
 WHERE a.login_id= :email
```